# Регулярное выражение не останавливается на подходящем выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `{!Check check}</span></span> <span class="some-class">Some text {!Price Price}` и регулярное выражение `\{!.+\}`. Мне нужно чтобы находило выражение по типу `{!любой текст}`. Но вместо того чтобы найти 2 выражения `{!Check check}` и `{!Price Price}` - находит целую строку. Как правильно составить выражение чтобы находило по-отдельности?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, нужно поставить `?` для ленивого поиска.
Правильное выражение `\{!.+?\}`